# Twitter Bootstrap Datatable not working properly with AJaX

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

Using this piece of HTML code is working fine as expected:

```
<table class = 'table table-bordered table-striped' id = 'example'>
    <thead><tr><th>Col1</th><th>Col2</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
        <tr><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is it:

[image: Correct view of Twitter Bootstrap Datatable]

But when I store the same snippet in a variable as:

```
content = "<table class = 'table table-bordered table-striped' id = 'example'>" +
    "<thead><tr><th>Col1</th><th>Col2</th></tr></thead>" +
    "<tbody>" +
        "<tr><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>" +
        "<tr><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>" +
    "</tbody>" +
"</table>"
```

and call it dynamically via AJaX, the output seems to be different as shown in this screenshot:

[image]

The pagination and the search field are gone! There is no difference in the code, but why is the second table lacking those features?

Comment: Why don't you request data (ajax) and let datatable do the job?

Comment: How is the ajax call being made? How are you letting the datatable know about the data that is being loaded via the ajax call.?

Comment: @RC What you've said is better, but I want to stay with this format as much as possible  because this is the pattern I have in this legacy system.

Comment: @Raghu The data are loaded together with the html table. In my example  above, I just want to correctly load the right features of bootstrap table - without db connection yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you add a table dynamically. You have to apply the dataTable() again.
See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/bassjobsen/8GNpf/

Or for example add a table when the button with `id="addtable"` has been clicked:

```
var content = "<table class = 'table table-bordered table-striped' id = 'example2'>" +
    "<thead><tr><th>Col1</th><th>Col2</th></tr></thead>" +
    "<tbody>" +
        "<tr><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>" +
        "<tr><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>" +
    "</tbody>" +
"</table>"


$('#addtable').click(function(){$('body').append(content);

$('body table').last().dataTable({
        "sDom": "<'row'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>"
    });});
```

Comment: I still don't know exactly how it works. But what matters now is it does.Thanks Bass.